# String method to remove a char sequence from a string

Tags: c#, string

If I have:

```
string st1 = "this.is.a.string.type";
string st2 = "string";
```

Is there any built-in String method to remove st2 from st1 if the exact sequence of chars exists in st1? So I want to end up with "this.is.a..type".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest would be:

```
st1 = st1.Replace(st2, "");
```

but that isn't necessarily very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
string st3 = st1.Replace(st2, string.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 for string.empty.  I know there's no difference but it still makes me squirm when I see "".

Answer (score 0):

This will work out for you

```
string st3 = st1.Replace(st2,"");
```

This will remove all instances of st2 from st1, and return the result

Comment: Only if the OP uses the return value. As a statement on its own (as shown), it's just eating CPU.

Comment: @Jon - I fixed it before I saw your comment, but that is of course absolutely correct (as usual).

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
st1.Replace(st2, "")
```

it will replace all occurrences though.